# How to create a pandas dataframe for the below conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
temp=[79,80,81,80,80,79,76,75,76,78,80,81]
for i in range(len(temp)):
        if temp[i]<=80:
            level=0
        elif temp[i]>80 and temp[i]<=100:
            level=1
        elif temp[i]<=75:
            n_level=0
        elif temp[i]>75 and temp[i]<=95:
            n_level=1//
        df=pd.DataFrame([[temp[i],level]],columns=['temp1','level1','newlevel'])//
        print(df)//
```

Unable to get the output which is expected to be like this

```
#temp# ##level## ###newlevel###
79   0     0
80   0     0
81   1     1
```

Comment: Please sort out your expected output.

Comment: The way you construct your dataframe isn't compatible with the constructor

Comment: The above is the one .. I have added the image ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf9Xg.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swbMp.jpg)
I just want to know whether we could use pandas data frame directly and use And conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below solution, I have used list comprehension to create the data required to build the data frame. Please change the conditions inside the list comprehensions to meet your needs. [Code and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MN3m.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
temp=[79,80,81,80,80,79,76,75,76,78,80,81]
level=[0 if i<=80 else  1 for i in  temp]
n_level=[0 if i<=75 else  1 for i in  temp]
#print(temp)
#print(level)
#print(n_level)
df=pd.DataFrame({'temp':temp,'level':level,'newlevel':n_level})
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your DataFrame using solely *Pandas* methods.
To generate both "level" columns, it is enough to use *cut*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': temp,
    'level1'  : pd.cut(temp, [0, 80, 1000], labels=[0, 1]),
    'newlevel': pd.cut(temp, [0, 75, 1000], labels=[0, 1])})
```

Note: Both "level" columns of the output DataFrame have *category* type.
If you are unhappy about that, cast them to *int*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': temp,
    'level1'  : pd.cut(temp, [0, 80, 1000], labels=[0, 1]).astype(int),
    'newlevel': pd.cut(temp, [0, 75, 1000], labels=[0, 1]).astype(int)})
```

Comment: u rock :) .Thanks for the help @Valdi_Bo